# Trouble Naming Ubuntu 15.04 Server Using Vagrant

Tags: web-services, vagrant, virtual-machine, server, ansible

I would like to change the name of both **user** and **machine** when logging into a VM. Currently I have `vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64` 
I have tried using `vb.customise` and the `--name` attribute but it does not change this naming convention within the terminal, but does change it within the `VirtualBox VM's` Directory on my host machine. I would rather it be `myname@dev1`, but do not know how to go about this.

Sorry for such a trivial question, but I am extremely new to VMs and nix based OS's.

**My Current VagrantFile:**

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/vivid64"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 8000

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "dev1", "--memory", "512"]
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "../../highsect", "/webapps/highsect/project"

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "vagrant.yml"
  end
end
```

Comment: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html

Comment: Now how would I change `vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but please try this settings to set username and vm name (notice the hostname is set TWICE):

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    ...
    config.ssh.username = "myuser"
    config.vm.hostname = "vm-myhostname-in-terminal"

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        ...
        vb.name = "vm-myhostname-in-vbox-gui"
    end
end
```

Comment: The hostname is set once - the second option `vb.name` is, as you indicated with the example, the name that VirtualBox gives to the virtual machine itself (as opposed to the host being run inside the virtual machine).